# NoSuchMethodError: Class has no instance method 'map'

Tags: flutter, dart

After i changed the structure of my json i try to create a model, i get an error:

**NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Translation' has no instance method 'map'.
Receiver: Instance of 'Translation'
Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => Carousel))**

My json response

```
[{
        "id": "1",
        "position": "1",
        "created_at": "2021-12-20 12:10:58",
        "updated_at": "2022-01-26 10:59:04",
        "translation": {
            "id": "1",
            "owner_id": "1",
            "language": "ru",
            "title": "Top Banner 1",
            "desktop": "/uploads/banners/banner.jpg",
            "mobile": "/uploads/banners/mobile-banner.jpg",
            "url": "#"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "position": "1",
        "created_at": "2021-12-20 12:24:58",
        "updated_at": "2022-01-12 13:26:09",
        "translation": {
            "id": "3",
            "owner_id": "2",
            "language": "ru",
            "title": "Top Banner 2",
            "desktop": "/uploads/banners/banner.jpg",
            "mobile": "/uploads/banners/mobile-banner.jpg",
            "url": "#"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "position": "1",
        "created_at": "2021-12-20 12:25:26",
        "updated_at": "2022-01-12 15:33:38",
        "translation": {
            "id": "5",
            "owner_id": "3",
            "language": "ru",
            "title": "Top Banner 3",
            "desktop": "/uploads/banners/banner.jpg",
            "mobile": "/uploads/banners/mobile-banner.jpg",
            "url": "#"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "position": "1",
        "created_at": "2021-12-20 12:25:50",
        "updated_at": "2022-01-17 09:04:48",
        "translation": {
            "id": "7",
            "owner_id": "4",
            "language": "ru",
            "title": "Top Banner 4",
            "desktop": "/uploads/banners/banner.jpg",
            "mobile": "/uploads/banners/mobile-banner.jpg",
            "url": "#"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "position": "1",
        "created_at": "2021-12-20 12:26:12",
        "updated_at": "2022-01-17 09:05:03",
        "translation": {
            "id": "9",
            "owner_id": "5",
            "language": "ru",
            "title": "Top Banner 5",
            "desktop": "/uploads/banners/banner.jpg",
            "mobile": "/uploads/banners/mobile-banner.jpg",
            "url": "#"
        }
    }
]
```

My model:

```
class Banners {
  String? id;
  String? position;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;
  Translation? translation;

  Banners(
      {this.id,
      this.position,
      this.createdAt,
      this.updatedAt,
      this.translation});

  Banners.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    position = json['position'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
    translation = json['translation'] != null
        ? new Translation.fromJson(json['translation'])
        : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['position'] = this.position;
    data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
    data['updated_at'] = this.updatedAt;
    if (this.translation != null) {
      data['translation'] = this.translation!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Translation {
  String? id;
  String? ownerId;
  String? language;
  String? title;
  String? desktop;
  String? mobile;
  String? url;

  Translation(
      {this.id,
      this.ownerId,
      this.language,
      this.title,
      this.desktop,
      this.mobile,
      this.url});

  Translation.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    ownerId = json['owner_id'];
    language = json['language'];
    title = json['title'];
    desktop = json['desktop'];
    mobile = json['mobile'];
    url = json['url'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['owner_id'] = this.ownerId;
    data['language'] = this.language;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['desktop'] = this.desktop;
    data['mobile'] = this.mobile;
    data['url'] = this.url;
    return data;
  }
}
```

My provider:

```
class BannersProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  Future<Translation?> getBanners({
    int? position,
    String? lang,
  }) async {
    var queryParams = {
      'position': position.toString(),
      'lang': lang.toString(),
    };
    var headers = {
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
    };
    String queryString = Uri(queryParameters: queryParams).query;
    var requestUrl = "${AppStrings.api}get-banners" + '?' + queryString;
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(requestUrl), headers: headers);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = json.decode(response.body);
      Translation? banners = Banners.fromJson(data[0]).translation;
      return banners;
    } else {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }
}
```

FutureBuilder:

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: fetchTopBanners,
    builder:
    (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot < dynamic > snapshot) =>
    Column(
        children: [
            if (snapshot.hasData)
                CarouselSlider(
                    options: CarouselOptions(
                        autoPlay: true,
                        aspectRatio: 2.0,
                        enlargeCenterPage: true,
                    ),
                    items: snapshot.data
                    .map < Widget > ((item) => Carousel(item))
                    .toList())
            else
                Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                )
        ],
    )),
```

My Homepage:

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  late Future fetchTopBanners;
void initState() {
    fetchTopBanners = Provider.of<BannersProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .getBanners(position: 1, lang: translator.activeLanguageCode);
    super.initState();
  }
}
```

I realized that the problem occurs at the json conversion stage, so I added Banners.fromJson(data[0]).translation to the provider, where [0] is the root branch.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Your question doesn't look complete to me, you have added `fetchTopBanners`, but it's not defined anywhere, while `getBanners` isn't referenced anywhere
Please update your question accordingly

Comment: Updated with fetchTopBanners in initState

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetchTopBanners` is a Future of Translation, hence it cannot be iterated as you've done

To return a list of Banners,

```dart
return (data as List).map((it) => Banner.fromJson(it)).toList();
```

To return a list of Translation,

```dart
return (data as List).map((it) => Translation.fromJson(it['translation'])).toList();
```

Now, your `futureTopBanners` will be either `Future<List<Translation>>` or `Future<List<Banner>>` depending upon what you returned from the above function.

now, inside your carousel builder, you'll have to create the Widget out of the data

following is the future builder's body

```dart
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
         return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
      final data = snapshot.data;

      return Column(
        children: [
                CarouselSlider(
                    options: CarouselOptions(
                        autoPlay: true,
                        aspectRatio: 2.0,
                        enlargeCenterPage: true,
                    ),
                    items: data
                    .map((item) {
                      /// this could be anything, just note that your list of data (translation or banner) is not a widget list
                      final someWidget = Text(item.title);

                      return someWidget;
                    })
                    .toList())
                
        ],
    );
```

Comment: Your solution working for me. Now I am getting incorrect data from json. Mobile banners have wrong url, Networkimage give error 404. Why he is return wrong url? Json response same in question

Comment: what error are you getting exactly? can you provide full error message?

Comment: i have wrong urls https://prnt.sc/26wbpuv

Comment: check my json urls in question

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think you're not using the full URL of the image, you'll have to append the baseURL and the full image url should be like `https://baseurl.com/uploads/banners/mobile-banner.jpg`

Comment: I use base url  "${AppStrings.localUrl}${item.mobile}", localUrl is string with url without / in end

Comment: the fact is that the links are not correct and a local link to the file comes from somewhere

Comment: fixed, thank you! you save my time

Comment: glad it worked, just out of curiosity what was the issue with the link BTW?

Comment: I completely forgot that I use multilanguage in queries. I was given links from the English localization, which I did not fix in the database. Maybe I need to rest :D

Answer (score 0):

As i can see your json you  have list of Banners so you can use **CarouselSlider.builder**  method to achieve slider like this.

```
    CarouselSlider.builder(
      itemCount: banners.length,
      options: CarouselOptions(
         
          viewportFraction: 1,

          autoPlay: false,

      
      itemBuilder:
          (BuildContext context, int itemIndex, int pageViewIndex) {
      return Image.network(banner[index].translation.desktop)
      },
    ),
```

Comment: if it does't help then share your api response. Thanks

Comment: I dont have banners for check length. Im using FutureBuilder with snapshot

Comment: can you share API response?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that there's only a `.map` method the code you posted, I'd say that the issue lies there, in the `snapshot.data.map<Widget>(...etc...)`. My wild guess here is that you expect `snapshot.data` to be a `List`, or an `Iterable`, while at runtime it turns out to be a `Translation` (whatever it may be). Do some debugging and see what type it is, and check the return type of `fetchTopBanners`.

Also, it might be a good idea to check the `connectionState` of `snapshot` before trying to access its `.data`, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this for your model classes. I do this for all my model classes and they are working.

```
    class Banners {
      final String id;
      final String position;
      final String createdAt;
      final String updatedAt;
      final Translation? translation;
    
      Banners({
        this.id = '',
        this.position = '',
        this.createdAt = '',
        this.updatedAt = '',
        this.translation,
      });
    
      factory Banners.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Banners(
            id: json['id'] as String? ?? '',
            position: json['position'] as String? ?? '',
            createdAt: json['created_at'] as String? ?? '',
            updatedAt: json['updated_at'] as String? ?? '',
            translation: json['translation'] == null ? null : Translation.fromJson(json['translation'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
          );
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => <String, dynamic>{
            'id': id,
            'position': position,
            'created_at': createdAt,
            'updated_at': updatedAt,
            'translation': translation,
          };
    }
    
    class Translation {
      final String id;
      final String ownerId;
      final String language;
      final String title;
      final String desktop;
      final String mobile;
      final String url;
    
      Translation({
        this.id = '',
        this.ownerId = '',
        this.language = '',
        this.title = '',
        this.desktop = '',
        this.mobile = '',
        this.url = '',
      });
    
      factory Translation.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Translation(
            id: json['id'] as String? ?? '',
            ownerId: json['owner_id'] as String? ?? '',
            language: json['language'] as String? ?? '',
            title: json['title'] as String? ?? '',
            desktop: json['desktop'] as String? ?? '',
            mobile: json['mobile'] as String? ?? '',
            url: json['url'] as String? ?? '',
          );
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => <String, dynamic>{
            'id': id,
            'owner_id': ownerId,
            'language': language,
            'title': title,
            'desktop': desktop,
            'mobile': mobile,
            'url': url,
          };
    }
```